# How is nutrient uptake in humans measured?

Tags: food, diet

There are many claims made about nutrient absorption, eg ["Juicing helps you absorb all the nutrients from the vegetables"](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2014/04/19/juicing-benefits.aspx#).  I'm curious to know how nutrient uptake is measured.

Eg is it a pure nutrients in vs nutrients out equation?  Or are blood levels of nutrients measured before and after consumption?

What ever the methods, are they reliable enough to support claims made about relative absorption rates of certain diets or eating practices?

Comment: Depends on the nutrient type. Typically you would need an distinct assay or a molecular sensor for each nutrient type.